# Getting location data from Google Fit Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-fit

I am trying to fetch location data from Google fit activity which I have added through mobile. I am currently using OAuth2 Playground to test the request.

The request URI i am using is : `https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate`

**Request Body**

```
{
  "aggregateBy": [{
    "dataTypeName": "com.google.location.sample"
  }, {
    "dataTypeName": "com.google.distance.delta"
  }],

bucketBySession:{
minDurationMillis: 1
}, 
  "startTimeMillis": 1522281600000,
  "endTimeMillis": 1522368000000
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "bucket": [
    {
      "session": {
        "modifiedTimeMillis": "1522382434459", 
        "endTimeMillis": "1522316136834", 
        "description": "", 
        "activityType": 7, 
        "application": {
          "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
        }, 
        "startTimeMillis": "1522316098654", 
        "id": "cfd891371580xxxx:activemode:walking:152231609xxxx", 
        "name": "Afternoon walking"
      }, 
      "startTimeMillis": "1522316098654", 
      "endTimeMillis": "1522316136834", 
      "dataset": [
        {
          "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.location.bounding_box:com.google.android.gms:aggregated", 
          "point": [
            {
              "startTimeNanos": "1522316101582000000", 
              "originDataSourceId": "raw:com.google.location.sample:com.google.android.gms:motorola:Moto G (4):cfd891371580xxxx:live_location", 
              "endTimeNanos": "1522316134619000000", 
              "value": [
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "fpVal": 9.7610998153686523
                }, 
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "fpVal": 76.626411437988281
                }, 
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "fpVal": 9.7616653442382812
                }, 
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "fpVal": 76.626708984375
                }
              ], 
              "dataTypeName": "com.google.location.bounding_box"
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.distance.delta:com.google.android.gms:aggregated", 
          "point": [
            {
              "startTimeNanos": "1522316098654000000", 
              "originDataSourceId": "raw:com.google.location.sample:com.google.android.gms:motorola:Moto G (4):cfd891371580xxxx:live_location", 
              "endTimeNanos": "1522316136834000000", 
              "value": [
                {
                  "mapVal": [], 
                  "fpVal": 83.398760318756104
                }
              ], 
              "dataTypeName": "com.google.distance.delta"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But these response does not provide a from and to location information which I can show in my website.

1. Is there any other `dataTypeName` which I can use to get the location information?
2. What is the bounding box data shown? Is it useful in any way to show location?
3. What is the data provided by `"dataTypeName": "com.google.distance.delta"` mean? Is it the distance between start and end location?

Comment: Why the downvote? I cant find any information related anywhere hence posted here

Comment: No one? Please update with a solution

Comment: I have the same issue here

Answer (score 0):

"Location data can only be read by the app that wrote the data. Your app can only read back data it wrote. It cannot read location sample data written by other apps."
[from developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/location#location_sample)