# Get .tcx data from Google Fit API

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-api

I'm trying to analyze session .tcx data from my own Google Fit profile. I can access this data using a Takeout export (https://takeout.google.com/) where I get the tcx files, but the export takes some time to process and seems to require manual triggering. I can get higher-level aggregated data via the Google Fitness API (https://developers.google.com/fit/android/) where it seems like Sessions information should make this available to me, but there appears to be no way to get the detailed information of the tcx file (e.g. actual GPS points and times); only summary statistics. Or if there is a way I haven't found it yet, and [Getting location data from Google Fit Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632393/getting-location-data-from-google-fit-api) seems to imply it's not accessible via the API.

I'm trying to build a process that would automatically update several metrics generated from the tcx gps/time data; is there a way to do this? Either to auto-generate my takeout export or to get the tcx information from the API somehow? I'm generating it for myself so I can get all permissions required. As it stands it seems like this data is locked into google, barring manual intervention, and I can't find a way around this.

Comment: "As it stands it seems like this data is locked into google" Yes, this is intentional. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54004208/3788176): third-party applications can only read location data that it wrote.

Comment: @AndyTurner So...if there are metrics I'd like to generate based on that data (e.g. that might capture the difference between an interval run and a normal run that have the same distance and duration) is there a way to generate those metrics? If Google doesn't generate them I, as the Google Fit user, have no way to have them calculated except to use takeout? That would seem to violate the purpose of having Google Fit; my own data is unusable without a cumbersome manual individual-based process. No way around this?